# How to write partial eta square in LaTeX?

Tags: math-operators, statistics

**Problem:**

Writing partial eta square in LaTeX. I couldn't find anywhere online giving guidance to this statistic symbol.

**Example (it's the symbol to the left):**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use the [amstext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amstext) package and its `\text` "command for typesetting a fragment of text inside a display", i.e. `\eta_{\text{p}}^{2}`, `SS_{\text{effect}}` and `SS_{\text{error}}`. When "p", "effect", and "error" would be variables then I would use the italic font/math as done in your example.

Answer (score 9):

The basic syntax in math mode for subscripts and superscripts is

```
<symbol>_{<subscript>}^{<superscript>}
```

The order is immaterial, so also

```
<symbol>^{<superscript>}_{<subscript>}
```

is legal and the output would be the same.

Note that this *must* go in math mode, either inline or display. So

```
\eta_{p}^{2}
```

is your friend. The whole formula, assuming it's displayed, would be

```
\[
\eta_{p}^{2}=
  \frac{\mathit{SS}_{\mathit{effect}}}
       {\mathit{SS}_{\mathit{effect}}+\mathit{SS}_{\mathit{error}}}
\]
```

although `\textnormal` would probably be better in the subscripts instead of `\mathit`. Do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in your preamble.